# List All Folders in Directory

Tags: vb.net

Can't seem to find a way to do this, google is failing me!

Please help, thank you!

Comment: "google is failing me!" -Oh really? https://www.google.co.uk/search?sclient=tablet-gws&site=&source=hp&btnG=Search&q=List+a+directory%27s+subdirectories+Visual+Basic

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
Imports System
Imports System.IO

Class Program
    Shared Sub Main()
        For Each Dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories("c:\Program Files")
            Console.WriteLine(Dir)
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

I am using the [`Directory.GetDirectories`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx) method which returns an array of strings, one for each subdirectory of the directory I provide as a parameter to the method.

Answer (score 5):

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("path");

di.GetDirectories();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
di = New DirectoryInfo(path)

rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)

For Each fi As FileInfo In rgFiles
    If CheckIfExist(fi.FullName.ToString.Replace("\" & fi.Name, "")) = False Then
        ListBox1.Items.Add(fi.FullName.ToString.Replace("\" & fi.Name, ""))
    End If
Next

Public Function CheckIfExist(ByRef Path As String) As Boolean
    Dim RetVal As Boolean = False

    For Each LI As String In ListBox1.Items
        If LI.ToString = Path Then
            RetVal = True
            Return RetVal
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    Return RetVal
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! While a code snippet could answer the question it's still great to add some addition information around, like explain, etc ..